# toggleClass jQuery class assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i assign the "navMenu__logo .transparent" to toggleClass? 
It will work with the .transparent class if i comment it out.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $( ".navMenu__logo" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "transparent" );
      });

    });
```

```css
.navMenu__logo .transparent {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

/*
  .transparent {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
*/
```

Comment: Your code will add/remove `.transparent` class to `.navMenu__logo`. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should have no space between:

```
// -----------v
.navMenu__logo.transparent {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Giving a space, you're telling the `.transparent` element is inside `.navMenu__logo` which isn't the case.

Comment: It its the problem with his styles.Then how "It will work with the .transparent class if i comment it out."-as he mentioned in question.

Comment: Simply using `.transparent` will also work. But combining the selector what OP wanted is like above. The difference is `.navMenu__logo.transparent` has greater specificity than `.transparent` which can be useful in such cases like toggling.

Comment: @simon glad to help you.